# menu links not going to category pages properly

Tags: cs-cart

I am designing the home page and category pages in cs-cart version 4
I have two links out of 13 that will not go to the right category page, instead its linking to the store front page...
the visual arts and film links and a ' A 403 ERROR OCCURRED' with the design link..(http://www.famethis.com/store/)
i have re-entered the correct info several times but its still occuring.
how do i correct this, all info is in correctly..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to enable the development mode in **config.local.php** to see more info about error?
Open your **config.local.php** file and replace:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);    
define('DEVELOPMENT', true);
```